# Intergrate Django, MongoDB and Sentiment Analysis(SVM)

Tags: javascript, django, mongodb, svm, sentiment-analysis

I have a django project, a mongodb and python sentiment classification scripts. I would like to integrate them so that I can visualize the sentiments in a graph with a javascript file or something. Please kindly advice. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Google Charts? You can use them in Django with [django-google-charts](https://github.com/mvasilkov/django-google-charts)

Comment: No not really. But I am looking at it right away. Thank you so much""

Answer (score -2):

You can try angular nvd3. Here is my website http://twittersentiments.com